# Transforming list into smaller subset in R without repetition

Tags: r, list

*I have searched enough but couldn't find the answer. If this is already asked please post the link.*

I have a list which looks like this

```
sample.list <- as.list(c("a","b","c"))
```

I want to transform this list like below:

1. {a,b}
2. {a,c}
3. {b,c}

I don't want entries like {b,a} or {c,b} etc. 
This is just sample list, actual list can be of any length

Answer (score 3):

We can use `combn`

```
 combn(sample.list,2)
```